# PHP MSQL application with AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have written a small application in PHP and MySQL. I have no problems reading and writing to the database. However, I'd like to use AJAX and while I have a form submitting via AJAX, I'm having trouble updating data on the main page

My main page creates a databse connection and then includes other, separate php files which display data from the database. I can't call these via AJAX to refresh them because they don't include the connection to the database when run on their own. I can't include a database connection in those files because it has already been declared when they are included on the main page.

Is there a solution to this? My code can be viewed at https://github.com/robertkent87/debt-manager

Comment: Posting a link to github with all of those files is not very attractive. When you create an asynchronous javascript HTTP request, you need to direct it to the URI on the server side that handles that request. The resource on the server should then do whatever it needs to do and return a response. The response body will then be accessible from that javascript object and you will manipulate the DOM in the browser to update it without refreshing the page. If you are new to the concept of all this I recommend using a library such as jQuery to simplify the whole javascript end of the process.

Comment: Have you ever heard about something called MVC?

Comment: Yeah, I've heard of MVC, I wanted to keep this simple though. I only posted my link to github because it's a bit complicated and I can't just post simple lines to illustrate my issue. FWIW I am using jquery

Comment: Your problem is clearly a design problem... I understand about keeping it simple but the overhead worth it to avoid problems like this. Now, which files you are trying to call via AJAX?

Comment: In `dashboard.php` I include the file `debt.php`. I'd like to update that with AJAX when the form is submitted but it requires a database connection. This isn't a problem when the page loads because the connection is created by `dashboard.php`. However, if I move the database connection to `debt.php`, PHP throws an error about redeclaring the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the redeclaring database problem with `include_once` instead of `include`